# How can I make my python binary converter pass these tests

Tags: python

My python code is supposed to take decimal numbers from 0 to 255 as arguments and convert them to binary, return invalid when the parameter is less than 0 or greater than 255

```
def binary_converter(x):

  if (x < 0) or (x > 255):

      return "invalid input"

  try:
      return int(bin(x)[2:]

  except ValueError:
      pass
```

The Test

```
import unittest

class BinaryConverterTestCases(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_conversion_one(self):
    result = binary_converter(0)
    self.assertEqual(result, '0', msg='Invalid conversion')

    def test_conversion_two(self):
    result = binary_converter(62)
    self.assertEqual(result, '111110', msg='Invalid conversion')

    def test_no_negative_numbers(self):
    result = binary_converter(-1)
    self.assertEqual(result, 'Invalid input', msg='Input below 0 not allowed')

    def test_no_numbers_above_255(self):
    result = binary_converter(300)
    self.assertEqual(result, 'Invalid input', msg='Input above 255 not allowed')
```

Comment: dont know if i'm correct, but the challenge is originally to use an algorithm function to create a binary converter.... all the tests failed for me...would really appreciate fresh eyes

Comment: `return int(bin(x)[2:]` has unclosed parenthesis.

Comment: `int(bin(x)[2:]` is a syntax error.  you want `bin(x)[2:]`

Comment: .... thanks a lot....i've removed the int

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already know how to check the range of the input argument, and how to return values.  Now it's a simple matter of returning what the assignment requires.

In checking for valid input, all you've missed is to capitalize "Invalid".

For legal conversions, you just need to pass back the binary representation without the leading "0b", which you've almost done (remove that integer conversion, as two commenters have already noted).

Comment: Glad to be of help -- you did most of the work, after all.  Remember to accept your favourite answer.  If you found a comment most useful, ask that person to write up and answer you can up-vote and accept.

Comment: ...just joined stackoverflow today, trying to vote had no effect. Would study through to know how to do all you suggested...thanks for the guidiance

Comment: Ah.  Maybe you don't get up-vote until you have more reputation.  Edit postings, review things, and do the other "new chum" things that give you a point or two.  Up-voting the comments to show you appreciate them (as I did) isn't worth any points, but it helps the site.

Answer (score 0):

So this is the final working code

```
def binary_converter(x):

  if (x < 0) or (x > 255):

      return "Invalid input"

  try:
      return (bin(x)[2:])

  except ValueError:
      pass
```

Comment: You don't need the outer parentheses for the **return**